# MVC 4 & Rotativa HTML to PDF Cover Page Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I am using Rotative with MVC 4. 
I have implemented custom swatches for create header, footer and cover page.
My customswaches is below code

```
string cusomtSwitches = string.Format(
    "--print-media-type  --allow {0} --header-html {0} --allow {1} --footer-html {1} --allow {2} cover {2}", 
    Url.Action("PDFHeader", "Controller", new { data=""  }, Request.Url.Scheme), 
    Url.Action("PDFFooter", "Controller", new { area = "" }, Request.Url.Scheme), 
    Url.Action("PDFCover", "Controller", new { data="" }, Request.Url.Scheme)
);
```

My PDF is not generating properly. Cover page inserts some space on top and I suspects it is because of Header. If i remove header's html from header, Cover seems working perfectly fine and starts from top.

I can understand Cover must not have header and footer that's why I have implemented cover. but still there is some issue. 
If I can get full HTML before generating actual PDF, then I can debug where is issue.

Is there any way to get full HTML before getting actual PDF with header and footer etc ?